# How to resize the Flutter ElevatedButton, OutlinedButton, or TextButton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So actually if we have a ListView or a Column, I struggled to resize the button
this is my code:

```
            SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 100,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return const HomeScreen();
                      }));
                    },
                    child: const Text("Upload"),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the `style` parameter of the `ElevetadButton`

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(50,100)),
      ),
),
```

ButtonStyle allows you to define also `maximumSize` and `minimumSize`

Answer (score 0):

So I found some a little trick for this, since if we wrap the SizedBox or Container is actually not working to resize the elevatedbutton. So my trick there is I wrap the Container/SizedBox with Center widget

```
Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 100,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return const HomeScreen();
                      }));
                    },
                    child: const Text("Upload"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```